# How to make vim correctly display the errors reported by jq?

Tags: vim

When I edit the json file through vim, I use jq to format it. However, if the json is incomplete, the error message given by jq will be filled into the editing area of vim. Examples are as follows:

Json file:

```json
{
  "demo": nul
}
```

Execute instructions：

```
:%!jq .
```

result：

```
parse error: Invalid literal at line 3, column 0
```

How can I make vim automatically create a window to display jq error messages instead of directly covering my editing area? Every time such a situation occurs, the command must be executed: u This is very troublesome.

Comment: http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/quickfix.html#errorformat

Answer (score 0):

If your main concern is covered editing area, try this:

```
:!jq < %
```

Answer (score 0):

As an immediately usable workaround, you can use `:help :w_c`:

```
:%w !jq .
```

which echoes the output of `jq` in the command-line without affecting the content of the buffer:

[image: :h :w_c]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ShellFilterPost` event to display error messages in a new window. Similar post: [vim filters and stdout/stderr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2575698/vim-filters-and-stdout-stderr).

```
autocmd ShellFilterPost * call ShowFilterError()

function! ShowFilterError()
  if v:shell_error 
    w! /tmp/filter-error
    split /tmp/filter-error
    wincmd p 
    u 
    wincmd p
  endif
endfunction
```